# React component returning cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$ of null after trying to access array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, reactjs

Here is the problematic component in question.

```
const UserList = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    let theList;
    if(this.props.data){
      theList=this.props.data.map(function(user, pos){
        return (
          <div className="row user">
            <div className="col-xs-1">{pos}</div>
            <div className="col-xs-5">{user.username}</div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">{user.recent}</div>
            <div className="col-xs-3">{user.alltime}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }, this);
    } else {
     theList = <div>I don't know anymore</div>;
    }
    console.log(theList);
    return (
      theList
    );
  }
});
```

Whenever I attempt to return {theList}, I receive a **Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$mincana79xce0t6kk1s5g66r' of null** error. However, if I replace {theList} with static html, console.log prints out the correct array of objects that i want. As per the answers, I have tried to return both {theList} and theList but that didn't help.

In both cases, console.log first prints out [] which I assume is because componentDidMount contains my ajax call to get json from the server and has not fired yet before the first render(). I have tried to check against 
this.props.data being null but it does not help.

Here is the parent component if it helps:

```
const Leaderboard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return ({data: [], mode: 0});
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://someurlthatreturnsjson',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error('https://someurlthatreturnsjson', status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="leaderboard">
        <div className="row titleBar">
          <img src="http://someimage.jpg"></img>Leaderboard
        </div> 
        <HeaderBar />
        <UserList data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This `if (this.props.data !== [])` will always be true. You might want to try `if (Array.isArray(this.props.data)) {...` or simply `if (this.props.data) { ...`

Comment: yup tried that as well as vijay's suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah OK, there were some interesting problems in here, but you were *so close*. The big one, with react you must always return a single top-level element (e.g. a div). So, your variable `theList` was actually an array of divs. You can't return that directly. But you can return it if it's wrapped in a single parent div.

```js
const mockData = [
 {
   username: 'bob',
    recent: 'seven',
    alltime: 123,
  },
 {
   username: 'sally mae',
    recent: 'seven',
    alltime: 133999,
  },
];

var $ = {
 ajax(opt) {
   setTimeout(() => {
     opt.success(mockData);
    }, 200);
  }
}

const UserList = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
   let theList;
    if (this.props.data && this.props.data.length) {
      theList = this.props.data.map(function(user, pos){
        return (
          <div key={user.username} className="row user">
            <div className="col">{pos}</div>
            <div className="col">{user.username}</div>
            <div className="col">{user.recent}</div>
            <div className="col">{user.alltime}</div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    } else {
      theList = <div>There is NO data</div>;
    }
    
    return <div>{theList}</div>;
  }
});

const Leaderboard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return ({data: [], mode: 0});
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://someurlthatreturnsjson',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error('https://someurlthatreturnsjson', status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="leaderboard">
        <UserList data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}); 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Leaderboard/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.col {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

To explain the fiddle a little bit. Don't worry about the weird looking `var $` stuff, I'm just stubbing out jQuery's ajax method so I can return some fake data after 200ms.

Also, for me jsfiddle gives me a 'bad config' message when I run it, but I close the message and the result is there. Don't know what that's about.

Comment: Omg you are a lifesaver. I encountered this error before when I was just starting the program and here it is again. Safe to say it's hammered in my mind now haha. I wish I had more rep to give you but i lost my old account. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out too trying to work this one out. React is *usually* great with its errors.

Answer (score 4):

```
return (
  {theList}
)
```

should just be

```
return theList
```

because you are not inside JSX at that point. What you're doing there will be interpreted as

```
return {
  theList: theList
}
```

That's ES6 shorthand properties syntax.

Comment: Ha, you know I glanced over that and thought *that looks funny*

Comment: It's usually a beginner's mistake with JSX. :)

Comment: edited question with your changes. still receiving the same error though. I'm pulling out my hair at this point :(

Comment: @astringentpattern do a console.log on the data from the ajax call - if it's `null` then that's it.

Comment: @Jeff the ajax call is returning an array of objects as expected

Comment: Aaah, the reason this doesn't work is that `theList` is an array of `<div>`s. Not a valid return value for `render()`. It needs a parent div, see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Error can also arise from accessing nested state that doesn't exist:

I lack the reputation to comment, so adding an answer for future assistance -- I ran into this same issue for a different reason.  Apparently, the error is triggered from an earlier error throwing off react's internal state, but the error is getting caught somehow. [github issue #8091](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8091)

In my case, I was trying access a property of state that didn't exist after moving the property to redux store:

```
// original state
state: {
  files: [],
  user: {},
}
// ... within render function:
<h1> Welcome {this.state.user.username} </h1>
```

I subsequently moved user to redux store and deleted line from state
    // modified state
    state: {
      files: [],
    }
    // ... within render function (forgot to modify):

```
<h1> Welcome {this.state.user.username} </h1>
```

And this threw the cryptic error.  Everything was cleared up by modifying render to call on this.props.user.username.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small problem with the if statement:

```
if(this.props.data !== []){
```

should be:

```
if(this.props.data){
```

this.props.data is null, if the ajax call returns null. alternatively the code could be more elaborate.

```
const data = this.props.data;
if(data && data.constructor === Array && data.length > 0) {
```

Comment: unfortunately any type of checking I do to this.props.data and theList doesn't seem to help. i just cant return {theList} for some reason, even though it gets populated correctly.

Comment: you are right, i updated the answer. it is data.constructor === Array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is how you want to do it, but it works for me.

**edit:**

```
const UserList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    if(this.props.data){
      return this.props.data.map(function(user, pos){
        return (
          <li> className="row user">
            <span>{pos}</span>
            <span>{user.username}</span>
            <span>{user.recent}</span>
            <span>{user.alltime}</span>
          </li>
        );
      });
    } else {
      return <li>I don't know anymore</li>;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you put up what console.log returns...or just the start and end if it is very long.

Comment: FYI this will attempt to return an *array* of divs which isn't a valid return value for `render()`

Comment: Good catch, sorry I am copying a pattern where I use an <li> thanks, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I rendered a stateless component and decided to remove the react-root-element (wrapping div) after rendering it with basic dom manipulation.

Conclusion: be aware of this, better don't do it.