# React router children caught in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am attempting to build out some nested routes with react-router.

My route are set up like so:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route component={Main}>
          <IndexRoute component={RepositoryList} />
          <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="admin" component={Admin} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

The `App` component connects the redux state and actions to the props of `ViewWrapper` with `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ViewWrapper)`.

`ViewWrapper` render method contains `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}` along with some other global elements.

Now `Main` contains the following:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.main}>
        <Banner {...this.props} />
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

My understanding is that `RepositoryList` or `Profile` will be pulled into `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}` depending on which route is hit. This is where I am running into problems, there is an infinite loop which is producing the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$s50mbbsix2n2nxx9dg8gmbo6r' of null

My gut tells me that `Main` is trying to nest itself inside itself when passing this.props.

I feel like this must be a common problem but have had no luck finding solutions that work for my case, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what's inside your Main component render function? The error may be caused because you didn't wrap everything inside a single tag like <div>. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653696/react-component-returning-cannot-read-property-reactinternalinstance-of-null

Comment: Updated the question with the render from Main

Comment: so both of your ViewWrapper and Main have {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}... i think this is the reason for the infinite loop. Any reason in ViewWrapper you need to use {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)} instead of {this.props.children}

Comment: The view wrapper has a global message component that is required for all views, i am using cloneElement to assign the redux actions and state to the child components.

Comment: I think you are using redux in a wrong way. You dont need to assign redux action and state to child components by passing them from parent to child. They are actually already global. Every component that needs to access redux store, simply use connect(mapStateToProps)(Component). If you need to change redux state, use dispatch and it will update all connected components. So it is strange for me that you need to use React.cloneElement

Comment: I was under the impression that you're supposed to pass down props to each component. through use of {...this.props}. It seems a little verbose to have to connect(mapStateToProps)(Component) each time.

Comment: Hmmmm okay, i followed a tutorial by Wes Bos and took ot as gospel. I am using {...this.props} quite a bit. I might need to take a step back and work on a app wide refactor.

Answer (score 3):

A big thank you to @Yongzhi for pointing me in the right direction on this one.

Okay, so it turns out I had been using redux in the wrong manner. I was passing props to all children that required them through {...this.props} which was hooking every component up to absolutely everything in the store. At the time this seemed expensive but I just went with it. This meant that the children prop was getting overridden. And it was recursively nesting itself.

It turns out I should have been connecting each component to only the relevant parts of the store with `react-redux`'s `connect` method. After that, simple using `{this.props.children}` worked for my nested components.

**A complete example:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const Component = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.globals.heading}</p>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { globals: state.globals }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

If anyone is in the same boat, [read this page on the connect method](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) and it will all become very clear.