# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$3im0dodlvm6' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to understand the cause of the error below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$3im0dodlvm6' of null

My application works without problems. On the console is displaying this unpleasant error.

**SOLUTION**

I admit the problem is occurring because my bundle.js was duplicated on my page and this was causing the problem

Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to narrow this down without more information. But in general, somewhere in your code you have something like: someVariable.__reactInternalInstance$3im0dodlvm6, where someVariable has a null value, and thus has no properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React component returning cannot read property '\_\_reactInternalInstance$ of null after trying to access array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653696/react-component-returning-cannot-read-property-reactinternalinstance-of-null)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wherever you are calling that object, the data request is not passing down correctly, so it is calling it null. Try console logging out the data object to see if you can get it first.